# after.roles is equal to None discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord bot which is coded in python. I want the bot to check whether the user's role is updated. Then I want it to print what roles have been updated.

This is the code for checking whether the user's role is updated. It then prints the updated roles.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    for i in after.roles:
        print(i)
```

The problem is that whenever the user's role is updated, and I try to print the roles, it prints `None` and I'm not sure why it's doing this. So I was hoping someone could figure out why this is happening.

EDIT:

This is the code I have so far:

```
Intents = discord.Intents()
Intents.members = True
Intents.presences = True
Intents.messages = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents = Intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is online')


@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    for i in after.roles:
        print(i)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error, it prints out the after roles for me just fine. Try enabling intents.members in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Comment: Yes I have that enabled

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I have added my full code and maybe you might see what im doing wrong

Comment: Try enabling default intents + intents.members

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thanks for your help! That seems to have fixed my issue.